# HTML section vs div and differences

Tags: html, formatting

What are the differences between sections and divs?
both you use as the same:

```
<div id='test'> Element1 </div>
<section id='test'> Element2 </section>
```

but what is for what?

and second question: i need to design a homepage... the content page should look like [this](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/de-de/products/surface) one... with different parts..what should i take.. divs or sections?

Comment: so i should use divs?

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/):

> The **section** element represents a generic document or application
>   section…The section element is not a generic container element. When
>   an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for
>   scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. **section is a blob of content that you could store as an individual record in a database.**

`div` is a the generic flow container. It is a block-level element with no additional semantic meaning.

Comment: and when special do i use what?

Comment: i said my requirement at the question..i think i need divs there because they are styled..right?

Comment: @user3104539:- Yes you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Yes div is the block level element and use as a container but section is a semantic tags in html5 for more better way to representation the html content.

Answer (score 1):

**DIV**

> The div element has no special meaning at all. It represents its
>   children. It can be used with the class, lang, and title attributes to
>   mark up semantics common to a group of consecutive elements.

[Click Here to know more about DIV](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-div-element.html#the-div-element)

**Section :**

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or
>   application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of
>   content, typically with a heading.
>
> Examples of sections would be chapters, the various tabbed pages in a
>   tabbed dialog box, or the numbered sections of a thesis. A Web site's
>   home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news
>   items, and contact information.

[Click here to know more about SECTION](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-section-element.html#the-section-element)

Comment: but at this section-form (contact) then divs for name: and message: if they should have special style?

Comment: actually you need to design the page as it is? right so you should have a sound knowledge in CSS

Answer (score 1):

The section tag is new to HTML5, which effectively means older browsers may have trouble with it. 
According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML/Element/section)

> •Do not use the  element as a generic container; this is what  is for, especially when the sectioning is only for styling purposes. A rule of thumb is that a section should logically appear in the outline of a document.